# map find the first non consecutive key

Tags: c++, stl

I have a map with integer as keys.
Using stl, I would like to find the first element that has not consecutive keys.

I should look like that:

```
map<int, int> m {
    {1, 1},
    {2, 2},
    {3, 3},
    {5, 5},
    {6, 6},
    {8, 8},
};

bool func(const pair<int, int>& a, const pair<int, int>& b){
    return (a.first + 1) != b.first;
}

int main()
{
    cout << find_first_of(m.begin(), m.end(), 1, func)->first; //gives 3
    cout << find_first_of(m.begin(), m.end(), 2, func)->first; //gives 3
    cout << find_first_of(m.begin(), m.end(), 5, func)->first; //gives 6 
    
    return 0;
}
```

I couldn't find any function doing this in stl, any help ?

Comment: Please define what are consecutive elements. The map has keys and values, but not elements.

Comment: I mean first non consecutive keys

Comment: [std::adjacent_find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Interesting enough that such algorithm exists – this kind of task apparently is more common than I ever would have expected ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua -- More infamously, this algorithm is (ab)used to go through consecutive pairs of values, where the predicate always returns `false`.  A quick and dirty way of processing pairs.

Comment: @tony_merguez -- In general, use `std::adjacent_find` whenever you have the scenario of testing if two consecutive items in a container meet (or do not meet) a certain condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [std::adjacent_find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) to search consecutive keys in the map.

Here is an example.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

std::map<int, int> m{
    {1, 1},
    {2, 2},
    {3, 3},
    {5, 5},
    {6, 6},
    {8, 8},
};

int main()
{
    auto iter = std::adjacent_find(m.begin(), m.end(), [](cont auto& pr1, const auto& pr2)
        {
            return (pr1.first  != pr2.first - 1);
        });
    if (iter != m.end())
    {
        std::cout << "The last consecutive element is {" << iter->first << ", " << iter->second << "}\n";
        std::advance(iter, 1);
        std::cout << "The first non-consecutive element is {" << iter->first << ", " << iter->second << "}\n";
    }
    else
        std::cout << "All pairs are consecutive";
}
```

Output:

```
The last consecutive element is {3, 3}
The first non-consecutive element is {5, 5}
```

[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/T4Eond1WM)

Comment: I would like to start the "search" from a start point. I replaced the first argument of `adjacent_find` by `m.find(1)`, and the returted iterator points to `m.end()`

Comment: [Cannot duplicate](https://godbolt.org/z/jhn765sK9).  Also [cannot duplicate when pointing to 5](https://godbolt.org/z/M5oG9qMb8).